# AJAX cannot access an object data value passed from php

Tags: php, ajax

I have a php.php file to receive data then pass the result back to AJAX, like this:

```
<?php

$p1 = $_POST["p1"];
$c1 = $_POST["c1"];
$resultx['r1'] = "XXX";
$resultx['r2'] = 0;
$resultx['r3'] = 100;
$resultx['r4'] = 1000;

echo json_encode($resultx);
```

And in my js file I have:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        p1: 5,
        c1: 100            
    },

    cache: false,
    success: function (resultx) {     
       var result = resultx;
       console.log(result);

        var my1 = document.getElementById('my1');
        var my2 =  document.getElementById('my2');
        var my3 =  document.getElementById('my3');
        var my4 = document.getElementById('my4');           

        my1.textContent = "Id : "+result.r1;
        my2.textContent = "Rank : "+result.r2;
        my3.textContent = "Total players : "+result.r3;
        my4.textContent = "Top credit : "+result.r4;


   },
});
```

The my1 my2 my3 my4 fields all print with undefined even though the console log show the value of:

```
{"r1":"XXX","r2":0, "r3":100, "r4":1000}
```

When I change the statement

`var result = resultx;`

to

`var result = JSON.parse(resultx)`

the javascript console prints a error message of `uncaught syntax error unexpected token`.

Please help!

Comment: You need dataType:'json'

Comment: ... or `header('Content-type: application/json')` just before the `echo` line